# How to access the Ubuntu filesystem in Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 as a Windows app in Windows 10. As far as I understand, this uses `Windows Subsystem for Linux` to run linux processes.

From the Ubuntu terminal I am able to access the Windows `C:` drive:

```
$ ls /mnt/c
```

How can I access the Ubuntu drive from windows applications, from example from the Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is indeed possible to access the files as Muhammed mentioned via `C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_*\LocalState\rootfs`, Microsoft strongly recommends against it in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/:

> DO NOT, under ANY circumstances, access, create, and/or modify files in your distro's filesystem using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.
>
> Opening files using some Windows tools may read-lock the opened files and/or folders, preventing updates to file contents and/or metadata, essentially resulting in corrupted files/folders.

Comment: Presumably Windows does something hokey to fake proper file permissions within its linux filesystem, which will break if edited directly with Windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the Ubuntu installer for Windows 10 yet but there is a great article on how you can access the Ubuntu subsystem via Windows Explorer: https://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/

Hope this helps.

Kind Regards,
Mo

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

There are [driver apps](https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) available, but I would advise much testing before you use them in a production environment. I say this because I have had three ext4 filesystems corrupted severely by the [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) driver in Windows 10 in a dual boot system when I used it to write into ext4 partitions, and their website cautions against ext4 use now.
  [Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) from Diskinternals is a read-only driver, which reduces risk.
  [Ext2read](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) also works with ext3 and ext4 as do the others. All the above are Open Source and free-as-in-beer.
  [Ext2 IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/) is freeware, not Open Source, and described as working with ext2 and ext3 with some ext4 features.
  A commercial product which says it supports [most](https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/linuxfs-windows/#faq) ext4 features ( excluding bigalloc, journal_dev, meta_bg, and inline_data ) is Paragon Software's [Linux File Systems for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/linuxfs-windows/).